# SQL Execution Error in MS Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

[image]

When I try and create a query in Visual Studio using this Access Database I get the error you see above.

The error is

```
Error Source: Microsoft Access Database Engine
Error Message: No value given for one or more required parameters
```

Every field in the database has some data in so I am unsure what this can be.

I have checked the relationship in Access and it works as it should. I have tried using Google the issue but found no joy.

Comment: doesn't look like there is a Carsid in the customer table..

Comment: This is due to the relationship type of the tables. Wouldn't adding this field changes the relationship.

Comment: @joshuahornby10 What is the relationship supposed to be? A customer can have multiple cars? A car can have multiple customers?

Comment: A customer can have many cars, and a car can only have one customer is the relationship I am after.

Comment: @joshuahornby10 Then a car should have a CustomerID field that references CustomerID in Customers. CarID should not reference CustomerID.

Comment: This is how my realtionship looks at the moment http://cl.ly/image/0Y0D41010r15 So you are saying Customer and Customer should be the link?